# The leg of an isosceles triangle; given base and area

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> The area of an isosceles triangle $\triangle ABC$ with base $AB=2c$ is $S.$ Find the leg of the triangle.

Let $AC=BC$ and $CH$ and $BP$ be the altitudes through $C$ and $B$, respectively.

I am not sure how to approach the problem. The area of the triangle is $S_{\triangle ABC}=\dfrac{AB.CH}{2}=\dfrac{AC.BP}{2}.$ What next?

Comment: A better approach would be to only use the altitude through point C. Try drawing a picture and see what the figure looks like from there.

Comment: Yep! I solved it this way, but the solution does not seem nice to me. We can find that $CH=\dfrac{S}{c}$ using the area. Then, by the Pythagorean theorem $AC^2=AH^2+CH^2 \Leftrightarrow AC=\dfrac{\sqrt{S^2+c^4}}{c}$.

Comment: "but the solution does not seem nice to me"  Well, gosh.... I'm sorry for that.  But ... what can I say?  Sometimes the world isn't all that nice?

Comment: "Yep! I solved it this way,..."  Why didn't you include your solution in the body of the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the definition of a right angle and the perpendicular bisector is that the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ is all the points $x$ so that $Ax = Bx$ and a right angle with vertex $M$ is one so that if $A,M,B$ are colinear with $AM = BM$ and $M$ between $A$ and $B$ then $\angle AMC$ is a right angle if and only if $AC = BC$.

So as the legs, $AC$ and $BC$ of an isosceles triangle are equal, then $C$ is on the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ and if $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ then $\triangle AMC$ and $\triangle BMC$ are two congruent right triangles.

Use the Pythogorean Theorem to find $AC = BC$ via

$AC^2 = AM^2 + MC^2$

What is $AM$?

> $AB = 2c$ so $AM = \frac 12 AB = \frac 12 2c = c$.

What is $MC$?

> $MC$ is the height of $\triangle ABC$.  The area of a triangle is $\frac 12 base*height = \frac 12 AB*MC$.  The area of $\triangle ABC$ is $S$ and $AB =2c$ so $S = c*MC$.  So $MC = \frac Sc$.

So what is $AC$?

> $AC^2 = c^2 + (\frac Sc)^2$ so $AC =\sqrt{c^2 + (\frac Sc)^2}$.